# CastCastException when casting to class loaded from a different class loader

Tags: java, groovy, classloader

I write a library and one of its API methods takes `Class` as a parameter, then in the body of this method I create an instance of this class:

```
void foo(Class scriptClass) {
  Script script = scriptClass.newInstance();
  // do stuff with the script object
}
```

The problem is that while `scriptClass` is a child of `Script` class I get `ClassCastException` as `scriptClass` was loaded by different class loader than `Script`. What is the usual way to resolve such collisions?

Comment: You can't resolve that except by using the same parent class loader (and thus the same `Script` class instance): the same class loaded by two different class loaders **are different classes** as far as the JVM is concerned.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer So something like `scriptClass.getClassLoader().getParent().loadClass('groovy.Script')` in the first line of the method should resolve the issue, even if `Script` was already loaded by another classloader?

Comment: I don't have enough context to answer that, but I doubt it. The thing is that the class *containing* `foo` must be loaded by the same classloader as `scriptClass` (or more precisely: they must share a common parent (or ancestor) classloader which loaded the `Script` class)

Comment: You can simply use a common ancestor -- Object, if there's nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast unless the class it *the same*, it is, its the same instance of Class, thus, loaded by the same class-loader.

**Common class loader**

Use a classloader that already has `groovy.Script` so when any child class loader use this class it's the common class.

When you use `URLClassLoader`, then use this constructor: `URLClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent)` to make the script use the existing classes.

**Other class loader**

If the above is not posible, you could use reflection (as JRE classes ARE common). But have in mind that this is a lot of boilerplate code and should be kept to a minimum.

So the bottom-line is *review your classloader structure and try to put common things in common places*.

Comment: +1 Common classloader is the only solution that works. He could write the framework in Groovy, but eventually, he will run into another place where the types must match (for example when calling methods on the `Script` instance).

Comment: @AaronDigulla actually the framework is written in Groovy and the method is called from a Groovy script. The reason why different class loaders are used is that the library is added as a jar.

Comment: Just set the existing classloader as the parent of the library's new classloader. That will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether your "scriptClass" is precisely "Script" or a subclass of it.  If the latter, then you basically just need to make sure that "Script" is loaded by the JVM before you load your "scriptClass".  If "Script" hasn't been loaded yet, your "odd" class loader will load it itself, creating your problem.  If it has already been loaded, the already-loaded (by the system class loader) version will be used in both cases.